# Xamarin - how to get locations from keyword

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, geocoding

As a junior developer with a little experience with Xamarin.Forms, I faced some issues.

I'm going to implement same features with iPhone default Google Map app.
As you know, Xamarin.Forms supports Map control and I added it.  I want to add address bar to search locations from keyword and I've researched about that but no luck yet.

I tried to use Geocoder but, as you know it has functions for getting position from address or address from position.  I cannot get address directly from address keyword using Geocoder.  However, I get all positions from addresses keyword and get addresses again from result positions but I'm sure it's really bad.  Besides, the search result is not good also. For example, when I input the keyword "Eiffel" on default iPhone Map app, I get more than 10 results. But my code using Geocode returns bad results. Because, Geocode searches addresses only, I think.

In a word, how can I implement native iPhone Map app search features on Xamarin.Forms project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can integrate Google Places API into your project.
https://developers.google.com/places/

Comment: Nice answer. I've checked the Google Places API and found that I can use it.

Comment: Do you have any examples for Google Places API integration or could you provide the link for samples if you have?

Comment: Any samples related to Google Places API's?